# How to reference a file that is part of a Chrome extension from within JavaScript

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, favicon

I have a Google Chrome extension that contains only a single JavaScript file, which gets loaded for pages in a certain domain. The script is very simple, it just reads the innerHTML from a particular element, then changes the title of the page depending on what the element contained. Code below.

```
var status = document.getElementById("target-element").innerHTML.toLowerCase();
if(status.indexOf("string1") != -1){ //Using String.indexOf() to check for substring
    document.title = "Title A";
}if(status.indexOf("string2") != -1){
    document.title = "Title B";
}else{ //Running
    document.title = "Title C";
}
```

This part works fine, and I wanted to modify it so that it could also change a page's icon as well. As the pages this script runs on don't ever have an icon linked in their header to begin with, all I have to do is add it and set it's relevant attributes. New version of the script with this implemented:

```
var status = document.getElementById("target-element").innerHTML.toLowerCase();
var iconLink = document.createElement('link');
iconLink.rel = "icon";
if(status.indexOf("string1") != -1){
    document.title = "Title A";
    iconLink.href = "icona.png";
}if(status.indexOf("string2") != -1){
    document.title = "Title B";
    iconLink.href = "iconb.png";
}else{
    document.title = "Title C";
    iconLink.href = "iconc.png";
}
document.head.appendChild(iconLink);
```

While this does successfully add the link tag, the icon comes up as not found because chrome looks for it in /icon.png. I also tried `./icon.png`, but the result was the same. What is the correct way to access a file that is part of a chrome extension?

Thank you for your time.

Comment: chrome.runtime.getURL('icona.png')

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Base64 to inject your icon.

```
<link href="data:image/x-icon;base64,AAABAAEAEB8AAA==" rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" />
```

Or you can try to use Web Accessibile ressource in your manifest.
https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/manifest/web_accessible_resources

```
{
  ...
  "web_accessible_resources": [
    "images/*.png",
    "style/double-rainbow.css",
    "script/double-rainbow.js",
    "script/main.js",
    "templates/*"
  ],
  ...
}
```

Comment: Web accessible resources worked flawlessly, thank you.

Comment: Fine.  Have fun with it